# Converting jiffies to milli seconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How do I manually convert jiffies to milliseconds and vice versa in Linux? I know kernel 2.6 has a function for this, but I'm working on 2.4 (homework) and though I looked at the code it uses lots of macro constants which I have no idea if they're defined in 2.4.

Comment: What is the function used in kernel 2.6?

Comment: @kaciula See jiffies_to_msecs() in include/linux/jiffies.h

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As a previous answer said, the rate at which `jiffies` increments is fixed.

The standard way of specifying time for a function that accepts `jiffies` is using the constant `HZ`.

That's the abbreviation for Hertz, or the number of ticks per second.  On a system with a timer tick set to 1ms, HZ=1000.  Some distributions or architectures may use another number (100 used to be common).

The standard way of specifying a `jiffies` count for a function is using `HZ`, like this:

```
schedule_timeout(HZ / 10);  /* Timeout after 1/10 second */
```

In most simple cases, this works fine.

```
2*HZ     /* 2 seconds in jiffies */
HZ       /* 1 second in jiffies */
foo * HZ /* foo seconds in jiffies */
HZ/10    /* 100 milliseconds in jiffies */
HZ/100   /* 10 milliseconds in jiffies */
bar*HZ/1000 /* bar milliseconds in jiffies */
```

Those last two have a bit of a problem, however, as on a system with a 10 ms timer tick, `HZ/100` is 1, and the precision starts to suffer.  You may get a delay anywhere between 0.0001 and 1.999 timer ticks (0-2 ms, essentially).  If you tried to use `HZ/200` on a 10ms tick system, the integer division gives you 0 jiffies!

So the rule of thumb is, be very careful using HZ for tiny values (those approaching 1 jiffie).

To convert the other way, you would use:

```
jiffies / HZ          /* jiffies to seconds */
jiffies * 1000 / HZ   /* jiffies to milliseconds */
```

You shouldn't expect anything better than millisecond precision.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the HZ value using CLI?  E.g. after reading utime from /proc/[pid]/stat on 2.6 kernel, can I easily convert it to seconds without need to compile it from C code?

Comment: If you're interacting with HZ from userspace, use USER_HZ instead.  'man 7 time' says to use sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) to fetch this value.

Comment: I don't see an obvious way of doing this from a shell script, but it's generally a constant unless you've been doing unnatural things to your kernel.  On x86 USER_HZ is 100.

Answer (score 16):

Jiffies are hard-coded in Linux 2.4.  Check the definition of `HZ`, which is defined in the architecture-specific `param.h`.  It's often 100 Hz, which is one tick every (1 sec/100 ticks × 1000 ms/sec) 10 ms.

This holds true for i386, and HZ is defined in `include/asm-i386/param.h`.

There are functions in `include/linux/time.h` called `timespec_to_jiffies` and `jiffies_to_timespec` where you can convert back and forth between a `struct timespec` and `jiffies`:

```cpp
#define MAX_JIFFY_OFFSET ((~0UL >> 1)-1)

static __inline__ unsigned long
timespec_to_jiffies(struct timespec *value)
{
    unsigned long sec = value->tv_sec;
    long nsec = value->tv_nsec;

    if (sec >= (MAX_JIFFY_OFFSET / HZ))
        return MAX_JIFFY_OFFSET;
    nsec += 1000000000L / HZ - 1;
    nsec /= 1000000000L / HZ;
    return HZ * sec + nsec;
}

static __inline__ void
jiffies_to_timespec(unsigned long jiffies, struct timespec *value)
{
    value->tv_nsec = (jiffies % HZ) * (1000000000L / HZ);
    value->tv_sec = jiffies / HZ;
}
```

**Note:** I checked this info in version 2.4.22.

Answer (score 7):

I found this sample code on [kernelnewbies](http://www.mail-archive.com/kernelnewbies@nl.linux.org/msg08850.html).  Make sure you link with `-lrt`

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec res;
    double resolution;

    printf("UserHZ   %ld\n", sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK));

    clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, &res);
    resolution = res.tv_sec + (((double)res.tv_nsec)/1.0e9);

    printf("SystemHZ %ld\n", (unsigned long)(1/resolution + 0.5));
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the USER_HZ value (see the comments under the accepted answer) using CLI:

```
getconf CLK_TCK
```