# convert jiffies to seconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I've got a piece of userspace code which is parsing /proc/PID/task/TID/stat to get the cpu usage.  I can use HZ to get the jiffies per second but this code could move to another machine which has a different configured value.  Is there any way to get the value of HZ from userspace at runtime?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731463/converting-jiffies-to-milli-seconds

Comment: This isn't a duplicate as I cannot use the HZ define.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You divide it by the number you get from `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`.

However, I think this is probably always 100 under Linux regardless of the actual clock tick, it's always presented to userspace as 100.

See `man proc 5`.

Comment: I did read that 100 is always presented to userspace... but wasn't sure /proc counted as userspace :)

Comment: I'm not certain I understand: does this mean that HZ is not actually the number that the questioner wanted?

Comment: HZ is the number I wanted... but it is a compiled in constant.  As long as I'm running on the same machine I compiled for... all is good.  But if I move to another machine without recompiling then it might have the wrong value.

Answer (score 4):

To clarify the math behind [MarkR's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3877285/1806289) answer:

`sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` will get you `jiffies per second`. Divide `jiffies` by the number you get from `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` to get the total number of seconds.

```
      jiffies                      jiffies              seconds
--------------------    =     -----------------    =    -------    =    seconds
sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)          (jiffies/second)             1
```

Answer (score 0):

Source of "ps" command include file `<linux/param.h>` to get value of HZ.

They also look for an "ELF note" with number 17 to find value of HZ (sysinfo.c):

```
 //extern char** environ;

 /* for ELF executables, notes are pushed before environment and args */
 static unsigned long find_elf_note(unsigned long findme){
   unsigned long *ep = (unsigned long *)environ;
   while(*ep++);
   while(*ep){
     if(ep[0]==findme) return ep[1];
     ep+=2;
   }
   return NOTE_NOT_FOUND;
 }
 [...]
 hz = find_elf_note(17);
```

I have to admit it look weird for me since ELF notes is a section defined during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

For shell-scripting, etc, use `getconf CLK_TCK` from the command-line. Use can use this to pass that parameter in as an environment variable or on the command-line.

```
main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    unsigned long clk_tck = atol(
        getenv("CLK_TCK") || "0"
    ) || sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) ;
    ... /* your code */
```

This uses the sysconf as above, but allows you to override it with an environment variable, which can be set with the above command.