# How to get the start time of a long-running Linux process?

Tags: linux, bash, process

Is it possible to get the start time of an old running process? It seems that `ps` will report the date (not the time) if it wasn't started today, and only the year if it wasn't started this year. Is the precision lost forever for old processes?

Comment: Here is a detailed page on the subject: http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/09/how-to-get-process-start-date-and-time.html

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `ps -p <pid> -o lstart`? Seems like it works, but I'm not sure why it's not the immediate obvious answer for the many times this question seems to come up.

Comment: @ajwood It would be better to use `ps -p <pid> -o lstart=` to avoid additional line (header) to be printed.

Comment: *Is there anything wrong with using `ps -p <pid> -o lstart`?* Maybe the fact there's no `lstart` neither in [2004 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/ps.html) nor in [2013 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) of POSIX 1003.1 standard?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, that would be a problem if the question asked about POSIX, but it's asking about Linux.

Comment: Note that `lstart` (and, I assume, `ps`'s other start-time fields) are susceptible to clock changes. If an NTP update occurs and changes your clock the output of `lstart` will differ before and after. I didn't anticipate that.

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274722/19157) offers a clever boot-relative start time which doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: @dimo414 Thanks! That's essentially the same thing as the accepted answer here though, no?

Comment: @ajwood no, the boot-relative start time of a process is going to be constant, whereas the elapsed time is always increasing.

Comment: This question is off-topic here, and was [asked on Serverfault in 2009 already](https://serverfault.com/questions/95643/linux-how-do-i-see-when-a-process-started).

Comment: Mods -  techraf, Makyen, David Rawson, Tsyvarev, Paul Roub - why don't you move it to a more appropriate site such as StackExchange or Superuser instead of closing the question? This is a good and useful question

Comment: I second @Hanxue's suggestion, especially because the referred Serverfault question has not really as complete answers as this one has. Also please consider how often this has been upvoted and starred _here_ on Stackoverflow compared to the very few upvotes and stars on Serverfault.

Answer (score 573, accepted):

You can specify a formatter and use `lstart`, like this command:

```
ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd
```

The above command will output all processes, with formatters to get PID, command run, and date+time started.

Example (from Debian/Jessie command line)

```
$ ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd
  PID CMD                                          STARTED
    1 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 /sbin/init                  
    2 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [kthreadd]                  
    3 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [ksoftirqd/0]               
    5 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [kworker/0:0H]              
    7 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [rcu_sched]                 
    8 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [rcu_bh]                    
    9 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [migration/0]               
   10 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [kdevtmpfs]                 
   11 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [netns]                     
  277 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [writeback]                 
  279 Tue Jun  7 01:29:38 2016 [crypto]                    
      ...
```

You can read `ps`'s manpage or [check Opengroup's page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for the other formatters.

Comment: When commands containing long strings some of the text is cut off e.g ` 3538 sendmail: Queue runner@01:0  4-05:19:43` How could you have the entire string printed? i.e not cut short

Comment: For those who want to use it on android, use ps from busybox instead, and the command column name is comm, that is `busybox ps -eo pid,comm,etime`

Comment: @bobbyrne01: change the order, e.g. pid,etime,cmd works for me on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: ps -eo pid,etime,cmd gave "error: conflicting format options" but [Adam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5731365/538192) below worked on Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Comment: hello, is "etime" the time the process is running or is it the time the process used cpu time?

Comment: @Gobliins - `etime` is the time elapsed since the process was started.

Comment: for completeness, for those used to BSD syntax: `ps axo pid,cmd,lstart` also works

Comment: @bobbyme01: use the -ww option

Comment: Be aware that `lstart` time can change, the `stat` methods below are safer - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274610/output-of-ps-lstart-changed.

Comment: When I use `ps -u USERNAME` I can get the processes run by a specific user. However, when I try to combine this with the above command (`ps -u USERNAME -eo pid,lstart,cmd`, or switching the order), it doesn't filter by username. How would you combine this command with the username filter?

Comment: ps: bad -o argument 'lstart', supported arguments: user,group,comm,args,pid,ppid,pgid,etime,nice,rgroup,ruser,time,tty,vsz,sid,stat,rss

Comment: Congratulations! This answer has been included in the BashScripts framework: https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/blob/trunk/bash_rc.aliases#L100-L102

Answer (score 51):

The ps command (at least the procps version used by many Linux distributions) has a number of format fields that relate to the process start time, including `lstart` which always gives the full date and time the process started:

```
# ps -p 1 -wo pid,lstart,cmd
  PID                  STARTED CMD
    1 Mon Dec 23 00:31:43 2013 /sbin/init

# ps -p 1 -p $$ -wo user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,lstart,cmd
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TT       STAT                  STARTED CMD
root         1  0.0  0.1   2800  1152 ?        Ss   Mon Dec 23 00:31:44 2013 /sbin/init
root      5151  0.3  0.1   4732  1980 pts/2    S    Sat Mar  8 16:50:47 2014 bash
```

For a discussion of how the information is published in the /proc filesystem, see
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/how-to-check-how-long-a-process-has-been-running

(In my experience under Linux, the time stamp on the /proc/ directories seem to be related to a moment when the virtual directory was recently accessed rather than the start time of the processes:

```
# date; ls -ld /proc/1 /proc/$$ 
Sat Mar  8 17:14:21 EST 2014
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root 0 2014-03-08 16:50 /proc/1
dr-xr-xr-x 7 root root 0 2014-03-08 16:51 /proc/5151
```

Note that in this case I ran a "ps -p 1" command at about 16:50, then spawned a new bash shell, then ran the "ps -p 1 -p $$" command within that shell shortly afterward....)

Comment: To see every process (not just your own) add an `e` (standard `ps` syntax) or `ax` (BSD syntax) argument to the ps command: i.e. `ps  -ewo pid,lstart,cmd` or `ps  -axwo pid,lstart,cmd`

Answer (score 28):

As a follow-up to [Adam Matan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731365/874188), the `/proc/<pid>` directory's time stamp as such is not necessarily directly useful, but you can use

```
awk -v RS=')' 'END{print $20}' /proc/12345/stat
```

to get the start time in clock ticks since system boot.<sup>1</sup>

This is a slightly tricky unit to use; see also [convert jiffies to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875801/convert-jiffies-to-seconds) for details.

```
awk -v ticks="$(getconf CLK_TCK)" 'NR==1 { now=$1; next }
    END { printf "%9.0f\n", now - ($20/ticks) }' /proc/uptime RS=')' /proc/12345/stat
```

This should give you seconds, which you can pass to `strftime()` to get a (human-readable, or otherwise) timestamp.

```
awk -v ticks="$(getconf CLK_TCK)" 'NR==1 { now=$1; next }
    END { print strftime("%c", systime() - (now-($20/ticks))) }' /proc/uptime RS=')' /proc/12345/stat
```

Updated with some fixes from Stephane Chazelas in the comments; thanks as always!

If you only have Mawk, maybe try

```
awk -v ticks="$(getconf CLK_TCK)" -v epoch="$(date +%s)" '
  NR==1 { now=$1; next }
  END { printf "%9.0f\n", epoch - (now-($20/ticks)) }' /proc/uptime RS=')' /proc/12345/stat |
xargs -i date -d @{}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [man proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html); search for *starttime*.

Comment: Slightly refactored for production use: https://gist.github.com/tripleee/2a1622fdf8ab080ce3b36d95af60010a

Comment: Bear in mind that the `strftime()` and `systime()` aren't present in `mawk`, which is the default `awk` in my Debian 8 VPS images, so I can only assume that they're specific to `gawk`'s dialect.

Answer (score 20):

```
ls -ltrh /proc | grep YOUR-PID-HERE
```

For example, my Google Chrome's PID is 11583:

```
ls -l /proc | grep 11583
dr-xr-xr-x  7 adam       adam                     0 2011-04-20 16:34 11583
```

Comment: This does not work for me - it prints modification time (changes frequently) 
Maybe because of this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created

Comment: The timestamp of the /proc/<pid> is not reliable.

Comment: This returned a time 9 minutes later than when a process I have information about had actually started.

Comment: This seems to be my only option that works, though maybe not reliable. I'm on an embedded system that only has busybox `ps` which says `invalid option` for all the options mentioned by other answers.

Comment: Why `grep`? Why not `ls -ldh /proc/$pid`? Or even better, `date -r /proc/$pid`?

Answer (score 19):

```
$ ps -p 182454 -o lstart=
Mon Oct 18 17:26:44 2021
```

But can I get the answer in epoch seconds?

Comment: Not sure if ps can report that directly, but depending on your environment you can maybe use command substitution to convert it: `date --date="$(ps -p 182454 -o lstart=)" '+%s'`

Answer (score 8):

```
    ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart | grep YOUR-PID-HERE
```

Comment: This will include it's own process too

Answer (score 7):

```
 ps -eo pid,etime,cmd|sort -n -k2
```

Answer (score 1):

use the command **ls -ld /proc/process_id** where process_id can be find using top command

Comment: This just repeats information from older answers, without the caveats.