# Nginx: when was configuration last reloaded?

Tags: typescript, nginx, ansible

We use Nginx across multiple servers and are currently running 1.11.10.

I am creating an Ansible script to deploy some configuration changes. The script copies the new configuration file to the server and then issues a command to reload the Nginx configuration.

Is there any way I can confirm that the file has been reloaded successfully? Using "systemctl status nginx" at the command line just gives me the status of the server and details when it was last restarted, not when the configuration was last reloaded.

Many thanks in advance for any information or help.

Comment: I use `nginx -t` to test it before I apply reload (and I'm not aware if there is even a way to obtain the last configuration reload time)

Comment: What you are asking is basically "[how to get the start time of a long-running Linux process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731234/how-to-get-the-start-time-of-a-long-running-linux-process)"

Comment: @hcheung it's not: processes are not restarted during the `reload` operation.

Answer (score 2):

That `nginx -s reload` return success(echo $?) tell us nginx load configurations successfully, but now the latest configuration may not worker for every request, because there maybe some connections with old worker are still not finished, at this time, the system has double worker processes as configured.

1. master-worker mode

   The master process load the new configurations and spawn new worker processes with it, then stop the the old worker process after they finish the already existed connections

   let's try with `worker_processes 2;`

   ```
   ✗ ./sbin/nginx
   ✗ ps aux|grep nginx
   larryhe         2572   Ss    2:43PM   0:00.00 nginx: master process ./sbin/nginx
   larryhe         2575   S     2:43PM   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
   larryhe         2573   S     2:43PM   0:00.00 nginx: worker process

   ✗ ./sbin/nginx -s reload
   ✗ ps aux|grep nginx
   larryhe         2572     Ss    2:43PM   0:00.01 nginx: master process ./sbin/nginx
   larryhe         2706     S     2:44PM   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
   larryhe         2705     S     2:44PM   0:00.00 nginx: worker process
   ```

   The second column is `pid`, we can see that pids of worker processes are different before and after `reload`.
2. single-master mode

   The master process apply the latest configuration within the process without restarting, it's done if `nginx -s reload` returns success.