# How to get year also in the startup process when doing ps -ef

Tags: linux, shell, ps

I am doing `ps -ef | grep process`.

I am getting an output in this format:

```
17297     1 12 Jan10 ?        02:53:26 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221-amd64/bin/java
```

Here instead of `Jan10`, I want `Jan10 2021`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the start time of a long-running Linux process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731234/how-to-get-the-start-time-of-a-long-running-linux-process)

Comment: You may be able to use the birth date of /proc/17297/stat and so stat --printf "%w" /proc/17297/stat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formatted output (`-o` option) of [ps](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) command and choose the format. For example:

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,lstart,cmd
    PID    PPID                  STARTED COMMAND
      1       0 Mon Jan 11 12:26:03 2021 systemd
      2       0 Mon Jan 11 12:26:03 2021 kthreadd
      3       2 Mon Jan 11 12:26:03 2021 rcu_gp
      4       2 Mon Jan 11 12:26:03 2021 rcu_par_gp
      5       2 Mon Jan 11 12:26:03 2021 kworker/0:0-events
      6       2 Mon Jan 11 12:26:03 2021 kworker/0:0H-kblockd
      9       2 Mon Jan 11 12:26:03 2021 mm_percpu_wq
[...]
```

Available formats are described in the "STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS" section of the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. If I am using ps -eo pid,lstart it is listing down all the processes. I want only one particular process which I am fetching from some name like this 
ps -ef | grep Java. Can you help how can I fetch this process only in the format Month day year for the start process

Comment: You do it using a pipe as you showed in your question : ps -eo pid,ppid,lstart,cmd | grep Java

Comment: I tried this ps -eo pid,lstart | grep Java but it is not showing anything, where as when I do ps -ef | grep Java it does show the output
17297     1 12 Jan10 ?        02:56:14 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221-amd64/bin/java
But I want:- 17297     1 12 Jan10 2021?        02:56:14 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221-amd64/bin/java like this in the format. The year should also append.

Comment: You need the complete command line ? Use the "args"  format for example: ps -eo pid,ppid,lstart,args