# How to find out how long a screen command has been running on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, time, server

I'm running a long script on a Linux server. To avoid getting kicked due to inactivity, I used `screen` to make sure the script runs to termination. It's been a few hours now and I'd like to know how long exactly the screen has been active for. The command I launched the screen with is `screen -S fragmentation ./fragment-all.sh`. I do not have root privilege.

```
yangsong@lanikai ~ $ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        852342.fragmentation    (Detached)
1 Socket in /tmp/screen/S-yangsong.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731234/how-to-get-the-start-time-of-a-long-running-linux-process

Comment: hi there, the problem was solved? if not, please specify your question by my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Hi cannot comment (yet) so ill try to answer here.
2. You can find the process id of the screen command that running by using `pgrep screen`. (process grep screen).

   - if you can't find the screen process by this command, then you can use `top` command to see all the process that running and look for screen process with his own PID (process id).
3. The output should be a number within few digits.
4. Then you can run the command `ps -o etime= -p "PID"` to see how much time the process is running.

   - change PID with the process id you have got from `pgrep screen` command.
   - The output should be the elapsed time in the format `[[dd-]hh:]mm:ss`.
5. If you want to terminate the process you can execute the command `kill PID`.

   - change the PID with the process id that you want to terminate.
6. **Another method that i prefer, because she is more readable is:**

   - `ps -o stime,time PID`
   - the output should be something like that:
   - STIME     TIME
   - 15:52 00:21:45

Comment: `ps -o etime= -p "PID"` worked for me ! :)