# Physical address of Linux "jiffies" variable

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to get the physical address of Linux "jiffies" variable so that I can read it by just reading the contents of this memory address.

Answer (score 4):

From kernel-mode code (e.g. a loadable kernel module) you need to include the `<linux/jiffies.h>` header file. It contains the definition of the `jiffies` variable:

```
extern unsigned long volatile __jiffy_data jiffies;
```

However, it also contains this warning:

```
/*
 * The 64-bit value is not atomic - you MUST NOT read it
 * without sampling the sequence number in xtime_lock.
 * get_jiffies_64() will do this for you as appropriate.
 */
```

I.e. you should not access this variable directly. It's a 64-bit variable and accesses to it are not atomic on 32-bit systems, hence the `get_jiffies_64()` function from the same header file. On 64-bit systems that function is a very simple inline function that returns the value of the `jiffies` variable.

From userspace code, on the other hand, you cannot access kernel memory at all.

Comment: To clarify: `jiffies_64` should not be accessed directly.  `jiffies`, however, is safe to access directly on all architectures (you will only get the low 32 bits on 32 bit architectures, which is usually good enough).  [See LDD3 chapter 7.]

Comment: @Eric Seppanen: It never even occurred to me to mention the 32-bit value. Been burnt a few times with it and 3rd-party kernel drivers of questionable quality - I saw the 32-bit value roll over on some of my systems and I had to deal with the aftermath...

Comment: Jiffies rollover shouldn't be a problem as long as you write correct code. That's why `time_after()` and `time_before()` exist-- to handle the rollover gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

For kernel code, use the functions defined in `include/linux/jiffies.h`. (`get_jiffies_64` for example).

[Kernel command using Linux system calls](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-system-calls/) illustrates syscall handling in Linux with a userspace syscall that reads jiffies. Could be what you're after.

[Linux obtain current of jiffies since reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/88820/linux-obtain-current-of-jiffies-since-reboot) over at superuser also has some information you could be interested in.

[Converting jiffies to milli seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731463/converting-jiffies-to-milli-seconds) is also something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is not *directly* related to your question but might still be relevant.
I maintain a small project (devmem-rw) here:
http://code.google.com/p/device-memory-readwrite/

It's quite useful to driver/kernel developers/testers; it lets one setup to be able to read/write *any* valid memory location- this could be RAM (user/kernel space), memory-mapped register locations, shared memory regions, etc.

Pl see the wiki area of the project (specifically, http://code.google.com/p/device-memory-readwrite/wiki/UsageWithExamples).

More relevant to your question, I use this project to demo a few use cases, one of them being repeated reads on the 'jiffies' value. Seeing that it changes proves the point..

From http://code.google.com/p/device-memory-readwrite/wiki/UsageWithExamples :

"...
Eg. 2: Reading the value of 'jiffies' on an x86 PC
The 'vm_img' kernel module mentioned earlier, also shows us the location of the 'jiffies_64' kernel global variable (which holds the current jiffies value); in the above run, it's kernel location turns out to be 0xc07c7a40. So:

```
# ./rdmem 0xc07c7a40 ; sleep 1; ./rdmem 0xc07c7a40 ; sleep 1; ./rdmem 0xc07c7a40
        +0          +4          +8          +c            0   4   8   c   
+0000   00 1a bc 20                                       ...             
        +0          +4          +8          +c            0   4   8   c   
+0000   00 1a bd 23                                       ...#            
        +0          +4          +8          +c            0   4   8   c   
+0000   00 1a be 1f                                       ....            
#
```

We can see how it's updated...(in fact, CONFIG_HZ=250 on this system, and some + factor is expected as well...).
...
"

Pl see the project page for details. 
It's been found to be quite useful for driver developers- for eg they can probe/change register values without writing code :)
Do give it a spin!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sources installed,

```
locate jiffies
```

schould reveal the .c and .h files, as in:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/jiffies.h
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reference `jiffies` from kernel code, that's exactly what happens.  What do you think needs improving in normal usage?  If you need the address just use `&jiffies`.

Comment: Though, apparently you are not supposed to reference that variable directly. It's a 64-bit variable and accesses to it are not atomic on 32-bit systems, hence the `get_jiffies_64()` function.

Comment: If you're fine with only receiving a 32-bit value, you can directly use `jiffies` on a 32-bit machine.  The upper 64 bits are there if you need them (and that's what `get_jiffies_64()` is for, but it's rare that you would need the full value.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to access jiffies values from userspace.

You can write a small module that expose the `jiffies` variable to a proc file.