# About linux kernel jiffies

Tags: linux, time, linux-kernel, scheduling

As a part of my assignment, I have to implement a scheduling class. I have written two syscalls, to record the sequence of the processes scheduled by kernel. Based on that data, I have to conclude, if it is Global or Local Scheduling.
1. I have taken and printed jiffies, pid, tid to kernel space.
2. By observing jiffies and sequence of pid and tids, I have to conclude if its global or local scheduling.
3. I have to know the time quantum that kernel allocates for each process.

My Question: Where can I look for that time quantum?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731463/converting-jiffies-to-milli-seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jiffies are used to count time units. Time quantum is the number of units the Kernel allocates for process or thread. You can conclude the quantum by observing the jiffies change between process/thread scheduling to run until switch to another process/thread.

Comment: I thought of that as a last option. Although I see changes that appear to be multiples of previous one, (which is the quantum), I wanted to confirm that.