# Compare jiffies with millisecond

Tags: linux, kernel

In kernel i want compare jiffies with millisecond. Can we do like this with 5 ms in if statement? Can you help me?

jiffies>5

Comment: Jiffies, as you probably know, are a measurement of time. Jiffies are usually about 4ms if you are using the UNIX timer that I usually user (forget its name, it's been awhile). So your comparison (if I'm reading your question right...) would be if (jiffies > 1), really.

Comment: i want compare exact time.

Answer (score 1):

From `include/linux/jiffies.h`:

```
extern unsigned int jiffies_to_msecs(const unsigned long j);
```

If it's there for your kernel, convert jiffies to milliseconds and compare as you want:

```
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
...
... if (jiffies_to_msecs(jiffies)>5u) ....
```

Comment: i use kernel 2.4, i guess it doesn't have that function

Comment: Use constant `HZ`, as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731463/converting-jiffies-to-milli-seconds