# Converting Jiffies to Microseconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, os-userspace

I want to convert the jiffies time that is extracted from /proc/pid/stat stats, I can convert it to seconds but I am looking for resolution in microseconds or nanoseconds if possible.

I have already looked at [Converting jiffies to milli seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731463/converting-jiffies-to-milli-seconds) but didn't find it much useful(maybe i did not understand it correctly).

So is it possible to make the conversion in user-space program?

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK))

If you have [getconf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getconf) installed, you can easily test this in your shell:

```bash
awk -vhz=$(getconf CLK_TCK) '{
    utime = $14 / hz;
    stime = $15 / hz;

    printf("%s: user:%.3fs sys:%.3fs\n", $2, utime, stime);
}' /proc/1/stat
```